# How to share .txt file in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, text, text-files, share

I have a problem with sharing **.txt** file in android (Kotlin). Sharing simple text isn´t problem. But I need share this file via Bluetooth, Gmail etc.
Everytime G-mail returns: "Couldn´t attach file".

my function for sharing:

```
  fun shareFile(file:File){
    val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    sharingIntent.setType("text/*")
     sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.absolutePath))
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with:"))
}
```

I have read all threads in this site but without any effect :-/

Comment: Get rid of `Uri.parse()`. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`. Also, replace `text/*` with the actual MIME type -- it is *your* content, and it is *your* job to tell the other app what specific type if is.

Comment: @CommonsWare why do you say that? I have found that the list of apps available to handle a specific text type (e.g. `text/csv` or `text/plain`) is sometimes smaller than those that can handle `text/*`, when you really want the broader set if you just want to attach/send the file, not process it.

Comment: "why do you say that?" -- because the receiving app has no way to know what the content is otherwise. "when you really want the broader set if you just want to attach/send the file, not process it" -- `ACTION_SEND` apps are certainly welcome to "process it" if their developers so choose to do so. If an `ACTION_SEND` activity, in its `<intent-filter>`, says that it only handles `text/csv`, and you try to hack around that by using `text/*` in your outbound request, the receiving activity might crash if your `EXTRA_STREAM` is not, indeed, a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have a solution of my problem, I´m posting it here for anybody with the same problem:

```
if (file.exists()) {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            file
        )
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.setType("*/*")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```